# create columns for Groups on condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas dataframe  df

```
id   key_no
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     3
```

in this specific key_no 's are associated with multiple id's

i want to create a new dataframe which has columns

```
keyno    start_id    end_id
 1          1          2
 2          3          5
 3          6          7
```

i.e create columns 'start_id', and 'end_id' for each keyno, in dataframe df2

Can we try using df.groupby , but how to create new df2 using that, i'm new to python, 
any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) by [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html). Last `rename` columns by `dict`:

```
d = {'first':'start_id','last':'end_id'}
df = df.groupby('key_no')['id'].agg(['first','last']).rename(columns=d)
print (df)
        start_id  end_id
key_no                  
1              1       2
2              3       5
3              6       7
```

Comment: working, one query, when you said `values in the column's are sorted` , you meant by the 'id' column right?

Comment: ooops, second solution was wrong, because last value is max only in sample, in real data maybe yes, maybe not... Similar for first and min.